# Django AuthenticationForm is not validating and not storing information in database

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates, django-authentication

So basically I'm trying to do a simple login system using Django AuthenticationForm and LoginView. The form takes the user input and when the login button is pressed, the page just reloads, instead of throwing validation errors or logging the user and redirecting him. I've tried to overwrite the clean method but the result is the same. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

This is the User model:

```
class StoreUser(auth_models.AbstractBaseUser, auth_models.PermissionsMixin):
  email = models.EmailField(
    unique=True,
)
  date_joined = models.DateTimeField(
    auto_now_add=True,
)

  is_staff = models.BooleanField(
    default=False,
)

  USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

  objects = StoreUserManager()
```

Here is the Login view:

```
class UserLoginView(auth_views.LoginView):
   form_class = UserLoginForm
   template_name = 'store_auth/user_login.html'
   success_url = reverse_lazy('homepage')
```

And also the Form:

```
class UserLoginForm(auth_forms.AuthenticationForm):
   email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': "email-login", 'placeholder': "Enter your email",}))
   password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id':"password-login", 'labels': "Password", 'placeholder': "Enter your password", }))

   class Meta:
    model = StoreUser
```

And the HTML:

```
  <form method="post" action="{% url 'user login' %}">
              {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email-login">E-Mail</label>
              {{ form.email }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password-login">Password</label>
              {{ form.password }}
            </div>
            <a href="javascript:;">Forgotten Password?</a>
            <div class="padding-top-20">                  
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button>
            </div>
```

When the fields are defined through the Meta class everything works fine, and the user is logged in and redirected successfully, but in this way, the field widgets remain unchanged because Meta is parsed by the metaclass before the **init**. I also tried to add the field manually to self. fields:

```
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
   super(UserLoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
   self.fields['email'] = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': "email-login", 'placeholder': "Enter your email",}))
   self.fields['password'] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id':"password-login", 'labels': "Password", 'placeholder': "Enter your password", }))
```

But again and the user is not logged in and the data is not validated. I think my mistake is in the field validation.
Аny help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show your `urls.py` for `UserLoginView` view?

Comment: Sure, here it is:  
` path('login/', UserLoginView.as_view(), name='user login'),`

Comment: When user is not logged in are you getting `errors`? something like `The two filed's didn't match, or username and password are mismatched, whatever you have defined?

Comment: no, I don't get any errors when I enter invalid data

Comment: The `path` function which you shared seems to be correct, but make sure you have imported it directly like `from .views import UserLoginView` then it is correct, or else if you have imported something like `from . import views` so you need to write `views.UserLoginView.as_view()`. check it.

Comment: No, my import is the following: from .views import UserLoginView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why your `__init__` method does not work well, but you can add the widget definitions in the Meta class:

```py
class UserLoginForm(auth_forms.AuthenticationForm):
   email = forms.EmailField()
   password = forms.CharField()

   class Meta:
       # AuthenticationForm is not a ModelForm so the line below is
       # invalid. Your User model will be retrieved through the 
       # AUTH_USER_MODEL setting
       # model = StoreUser  
       fields = ['email', 'password']
       widgets = {
           'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': "email-login", 'placeholder': "Enter your email",}),
           'password': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id':"password-login", 'labels': "Password", 'placeholder': "Enter your password", })
       }
```

Let me know if it works :)

Comment: It works like a charm! Thank you so much! I'm also thinking of a mixin option to take care of the form fields and set up the fields changes in the __init__ of the form.